# How do I split byte sequence in ruby and keep the delimeter?

Tags: ruby, byte, reverse-engineering

I am reading a database file with dynamically sized columns in HEX in Ruby. I can successfully split the file into records by using this script:

```
open_file = IO.binread(path + file_name)
record_delimeters = ['FAFA', 'FEFE', 'FDFD']

# regex with bytes is kinda finicky.. So I went this route to avoid the pitfalls of escape characters and gsub... If anyone knows a better way to do this part, I am up for suggestions as well..
final_reg = '['
record_delimeters.each_with_index do |delim, index|
  standard_string = '\xFA-\xFA'
  standard_string[2,2] = delim[0,2]
  standard_string[7,2] = delim[2,2]
  unless index == 0
    final_reg += '|'
  end
  final_reg += standard_string
end

final_reg += ']+'

reg = Regexp.new final_reg.encode('UTF-8'), Regexp::IGNORECASE | Regexp::MULTILINE, 'n'

records = open_file.split(reg);nil
```

However, I would like to keep my delimiters as reference because the delimiter denotes all of the 'type' contents of the record. ie: 'uint, int, word, etc...'.

Ultimately I want the records to look like this:

```
 ["\xFE\xFE\x00\xF4\x35...", "\xFA\xFA\x03\x4F\x7A...", ...]
```

OR this:

```
 ["\xFE\xFE", "\x00\xF4\x35...", "\xFA\xFA", "\x03\x4F\x7A...", ...]
```

BUT DEFINITELY NOT THIS(Which is what I have):

```
 ["\x00\xF4\x35...", "\x03\x4F\x7A...", ...]
```

Comment: Note the doc for [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) states: "If [regex] pattern contains groups, the respective matches will be returned in the array as well.". Does that help? Aside: you can write: `final_reg += '|' unless index == 0`.

Comment: `open_file.split(/(?=\xFA\xFA|\xFD\xFD|\xFE\xFE)/n)`?

Comment: @cremno that works great.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland I appreciate the help. Why did you take down your post on my other question?

Comment: Good to know. I wasn't sure at all that I've understood the intention behind the manual regex building. It's equivalent to `/[\xFA-\xFA|\xFE-\xFE|\xFD-\xFD]+/imn` which is just weird: `\xFA-\xFA` is the same as just `\xFA`, it matches `|`, why ignorecase and multiline?

Comment: Peter, I deleted my answer because I concluded it wasn't relevant.

Comment: Actually I cant get the records to pull back propperly without those commands... They were relics from a copy and paste but after removing them it was not returning the records correctly?